Is there a simple way to query with Panache similar to Spring Data
I have two entities with a OneToOne relation. I want to query the main Entity by a value on the secondary entity:
@Entity
public class Main {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.UUID)
    private String oid;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "main")
    private Secondary secondary;
}

@Entity
public class Secondary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.UUID)
    private String oid;
    
    private String value;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "oid")
    private Main main;
}

In Spring Data this is straight forward with a repository method:
findBySecondary_Value(String value)
Do I need to use a native query or JPQL for that or is there a way with the static find method from PanacheEntityBase?

I'm not quite sure what you mean with findBySecondary_Value(..), I'm not that familiar with Spring (Data), but you can query from the Secondary the Main entity, like this:
public static Secondary findByMainValue(String value) {
   return find("main.field = ?1", value).firstResult(); //or return optional
}


I meant the other way round, but maybe this will work as well. I'll need to check this, thanks.
